# WPF Catch Focus Change of Children Controls

Tags: wpf, user-controls, focus, tabcontrol

Is there a way for a UserControl to catch focus change on any of its children controls?

I've got a `TabControl` which has a UserControl on each tab. I am trying to maintain focus on control items when switching between tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `LostFocus` event of each control within the usercontrol.

To automatically do this, you can subscribe on the on initialize and loop through children. However, you'll either need to know your children directly (as in they are member variables), or your usercontrol will have to be/contain an ItemsControl.

If you contain an items control from a template, you'll have to search for the template control using the name you assigned the part.

```
<ControlTemplate>
 <Grid x:Name="PART_ChildrenContainer">
  <ItemsPresenter> <!--This will contain your children-->
 </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then you'll have to do the following.

```
var grid = (Grid)this.Template.FindName("PART_ChildrenContainer",...);
foreach(var child in grid.Children)
{
   child.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus += 
       new System.Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler(eventHandler);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution. However, after banging my head on the keyboard for quite a while I came across what I believe to be the best solution. That was to override the OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus method.